# mariasql how to get values from table and insert into another table

Tags: database, mariadb

hello first off sorry for bad explain but ill try my best

so im having 2 table

table 1 = sb_admins and
has COLUMNS =

```
 1. aid (AUTO_INCREMENT)
 2. user
 3. auth
 4. passoword
 5. gid
 6. email
```

table 2 = sb_admins_servers_groups and
has COLUMNS =

```
 1. admin_id
 2. group_id
 3. srv_group_id
 4. server_id
```

I need to get values from aid to admin_id with a INSERT INTO

what i have try but failed

```
INSERT INTO sb_admins_servers_groups (admin_id, group_id, srv_group_id, server_id)
SELECT aid FROM sb_admins
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT 
INTO        sb_admins_servers_groups ( 
              admin_id, 
              group_id, 
              srv_group_id, 
              server_id
            )  
VALUES (
  (
    SELECT    aid 
    FROM      sb_admins 
    WHERE     authid = '{steamid}'
  ), 
              '1', 
              '1', 
              '-1'
)
```